# Windows 7 took over my computer?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, raid

Yesterday, I had RAID installed on my computer with Windows 7. I deleted the RAID so it would wipe both drives, and then installed Ubunutu on the first HD. Today, I went into Ubuntu, used Gparted to partition the second HD so I could have Windows 7 on the second. After I finished instlling Windows 7 on the second drive, it does not give me the option to pick Ubuntu or Windows 7 on startup. Is it not showing because its starting the second HD on startup by default and not the first? I would really like to know how I can boot back into my Ubuntu. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

From this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999

> 4)    Re-install GRUB
>
> Now you have windows 7 but it has
>   completely eaten your boot loader so
>   you need to re-install grub.  Boot
>   from the ubuntu live cd and go to
>   terminal. Type in terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo grub
> grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
> ```
>
> That should return your Ubuntu
>   partition in the form of (hdX,Y), use
>   that:
>
> ```
> grub> root (hdX,Y)
> grub> setup (hd0)
> grub> quit
> ```